# ZK GAE : Disabling Java classes

Tags: java, google-app-engine, zk

is it possible to prevent the whole project from loading certain classes or by disabling it?

I got something like this warning in my log in GAE

```
org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.DefinitionLoaders parseLang:410
WARNING: Component captcha ignored. Reason: unable to load org.zkoss.zul.Captcha due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Font is a restricted class. 
Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.

This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. 
This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
```

It might be just a warning but somehow it takes a longer time to load the page. For this case, I want GAE or ZK to prevent `org.zkoss.zul.Captcha` from loading as it contain the `java.awt.font` which is restricted for GAE.

Comment: simply remove it from jar or classpath

Comment: @IgorArtamonov after i remove it manually i got this warning `org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.DefinitionLoaders parseLang: Component captcha ignored. Reason: unable to load org.zkoss.zul.Captcha due to java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.zkoss.zul.Captcha` and `This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.`

Comment: so remove this component if you don'l like such warning in logs. anyway, you've prevented class from loading, that was what you've asked